# How to get status of uploading file in Flask

Tags: python, file-upload, flask

There is a need to add some kind of an upload progress dialog to my application. I know there are plenty of Flash/Java/HTML5 solutions for that, however they are not suitable in my case.

Flask [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/fileuploads/) gives "an easier solution" offering [Flask-Uploads](http://packages.python.org/Flask-Uploads/) extension. However I haven't found any kind of solution for my question there.

*Is there any possibility to get the status of uploading file (i.e. number of bytes already uploaded)?*

In fact, I know that Flask accumulates the file data in memory if file size is not big. Otherwise, it stores the file in the temporary folder. If there are no options of getting the number of received bytes, maybe there are ways of getting the temp filename at least?

Any kind of tricks are very welcome.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is related to Flask

Please see this link:

- [Upload to Django with progress bar using Ajax and jQuery Laurent Luce's Blog](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/upload-to-django-with-progress-bar-using-ajax-and-jquery/)

I think these are be helpful

```
request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'], request.GET['X-Progress-ID']
```

Comment: I have tried to apply Django approach to Werkzeug. I don't see the connectors. `X-Progress-ID` seems like an envvar of Apache extension.

Answer (score 0):

I've yet to test it but I found a link to something similar [here](https://github.com/kirsle/flask-multi-upload)